# Problem with login control

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" 
        FailureText="חיבורך לא הייה מוצלח. אנא נסה שנית" LoginButtonText="התחבר" 
        PasswordLabelText="סיסמה:" PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="יש צורך בסיסמה" 
        RememberMeText="זכור אותי פעם הבאה" TitleText="" UserNameLabelText="שם משתמש:" 
        UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="יש צורך בשם משתמש" Height="100px" 
        DestinationPageUrl="~/AllQuestions.aspx" PasswordRecoveryText="שכחת סיסמה" 
        PasswordRecoveryUrl="~/RetrievePassword.aspx" RememberMeSet="True" 
        onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">

    <CheckBoxStyle Height="50px" />
    <ValidatorTextStyle BorderColor="#CC0000" />
</asp:Login>
```

The control works only without this part:   `onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate"` with that part included, it wont let me login!!!

I dont know why though :(

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{

    if (UsefulStaticMethods.CheckIfUserISbanned(Login1.UserName))
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/Banned.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening?  Error?  Nothing?

Comment: When you debug the code is it reached? and is CheckIfUserISbanned behaving correctly? Or if you are getting and error what is it?

Comment: AS i  said... there is no error... The default message appears: "You cant login, Try again"

Comment: I do get to the conditional statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to se the `Authenticated` flag.  [MSDN AuthenticateEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.authenticateeventargs.aspx)

Authenticated:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether a user's authentication attempt succeeded.

You need to add the code:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e){
    if (UsefulStaticMethods.CheckIfUserISbanned(Login1.UserName)) {
        e.Authenticated = false;
        Server.Transfer("~/Banned.aspx");
    }else{
       //authenticate...
       e.Authenticated = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked..i got stuck on this for 4 hours...luckily now it works..Why does it work now?

Comment: If you read the link I sent it says:  `Custom authentication schemes for a Web site use the Authenticated property to indicate whether a user's login attempt succeeded.`  You need to tell asp that you have validated this persons credentials.  Are you trying to do something *after* a user has authenticated?

Comment: only to redirect him to the home page.. But it does redirect him to hte home page

Answer (score 0):

If you add a subscriber to the OnAuthenticate event handler, the Login control bypasses its own authentication and turns over full control to the subscriber. You now you have to handle the authentication on your own (which is pretty simple, as shown below)

If you reflect on Login.OnAuthenticate, it looks like this:

```
namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls
{
    public class Login : CompositeControl
    {
        // other code omitted

        protected virtual void OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            AuthenticateEventHandler handler = this.Authenticate;

            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
            else
                this.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(e);
        }

        private void AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            var provider = LoginUtil.GetProvider(this.MembershipProvider);
            e.Authenticated = provider.ValidateUser(
                    this.UserNameInternal, this.PasswordInternal);
        }
    }
}
```